# While loop background worker broken

Tags: java, while-loop, backgroundworker

I recently made a application which makes backups for websites. There is one part which makes backups for the website and one part for the databases.

After I had the application running with hard coded data I decided it would be better to use a .txt file to read values out of so there is no need to change the data in the java application. This so that you don' t have to recompile the application everytime you add a website.

After I did add that .txt reade my while loop stopped working and I had no idea why. Maybe I made a basic mistake but I don't see what. I hope you can help.

I included a if function because the reading of the text file reads stuff twice so it won't try and open datbases with the name root:

```
if (!"root".equals(dbName)) {
  executeCmd = init + command;
  String printDate = new SimpleDateFormat(" yyyy-MM-dd - HH  mm ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
  JTextArea.append("\n" + printDate + executeCmd);
  /*NOTE: Executing the command here*/
  Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
  processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
}
```

I thought it might be this but when I disable it nothing changes.

I currently have this code(I disabled the ip adress etc)

```
public class executeCmd1 {
    public String dbName;
    public String dbUser;
    public String part1;
    public String part2;
    public String executeCmd;
    public int processComplete;

    public void executeCmd1() {
        worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Tekst1");
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Tekst2");
                        System.out.println("Reading File from Java code");
                        //Name of the file
                        //*NOTE: Getting path to the Jar file being executed*/
                        //*NOTE: YourImplementingClass-> replace with the class executing the code*/
                        CodeSource codeSource = executeCmd1.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
                        File jarFile = new File(codeSource.getLocation().toURI().getPath());
                        String jarDir = jarFile.getParentFile().getPath();

                        String fileName = "Textfile\\textfile.txt";
                        //Create object of FileReader
                        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);


                        //Instantiate the BufferedReader Class
                        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

                        //Variable to hold the one line data
                        String line;

                        // Read file line by line and print on the console
                        line = bufferReader.readLine();
                        String[] strs = line.split("-");
                        System.out.println("Substrings length:" + strs.length);
                        for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
                            String onderdelen = (strs[i] + "-" + strs[(i + 1)]);

                            String[] parts = onderdelen.split(Pattern.quote("-"));
                            part1 = parts[0];
                            part2 = parts[1];
                            System.out.println(part1 + " " + part2);

                            //Close the buffer reader
                            bufferReader.close();

                            /*NOTE: Creating Database Constraints*/
                            dbName = part1;
                            dbUser = part2;

                            /*NOTE: Creating Path Constraints for folder saving*/
                            //*NOTE: Here the backup folder is created for saving inside it*/
                            String folderPath = jarDir + "\\backup";

                            /*NOTE: Creating Folder if it does not exist*/
                            File f1 = new File(folderPath);
                            f1.mkdir();

                            /*NOTE: Creating Path Constraints for backup saving*/
                            //*NOTE: Here the backup is saved in a folder called backup with the name backup.sql*/
                            String init = "cmd /c start timeout 0 & cd /d C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\ & ";
                            String checkoutDate = new SimpleDateFormat(" yyyy-MM-dd - HH  mm ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                            String command = "mysqldump -P 3306 -h 192.168.50.166 -u " + dbUser + " --databases " + dbName + " -r \"%cd%\\backup\\backup " + checkoutDate + dbName + " file.sql\" & start cmd /c echo fisished ^& timeout 5";
                            JTextArea.append("\n Er wordt een backup gemaakt van " + dbName + " en op de gebruiker " + dbUser);
                            /*NOTE: Used to create a cmd command*/
                            if (!"root".equals(dbName)) {
                                executeCmd = init + command;
                                String printDate = new SimpleDateFormat(" yyyy-MM-dd - HH  mm ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                                JTextArea.append("\n" + printDate + executeCmd);
                                /*NOTE: Executing the command here*/
                                Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
                                processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

                            }
                            /*NOTE: processComplete=0 if correctly executed, will contain other values if not*/
                            if (processComplete == 0) {
                                String printDate = new SimpleDateFormat(" yyyy-MM-dd - HH  mm ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                                JTextArea.append("\n" + printDate + " Backup van datbase compleet");
                            } else {
                                String printDate = new SimpleDateFormat(" yyyy-MM-dd - HH  mm ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                                JTextArea.append("\n" + printDate + " Backup van database mislukt");
                            }
                            Thread.sleep(4000);
                        }

                    } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
                        return null;

                    }
                    System.out.println("Tekst3");
                }
            }

        };
        worker.execute();
        System.out.println("Tekst4");
    }
}
```

If necessary I can provide the code before I uncluded the text file to show the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in the for loop which read values out of the .txt file.

It was searching for values which weren't there so it crashed in the for loop.

The fixe of that loop looks like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < (strs.length - 1); i++) {
System.out.println("start of for loop");
String onderdelen = (strs[i] + "-" + strs[(i + 1)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You provided very detailed code, maybe you could strip down your example a bit.

I think the problem is that you open the file, read one line, split the line and for each substring you close the BufferedReader. You should only close the BufferedReader once.

My suggestion is to use java.util.Properties to read the file (Properties.load(Reader)). Then you can read the values in your File with getProperty().